# How can I specify docker image specification for fabric maven plugin

Tags: openshift, fabric8-maven-plugin

I am trying to deploy a simple spring-boot application in openshift using maven fabric plugin. I use fabric resource fragments method as explained [here](https://maven.fabric8.io/#resource-fragments). I don't have any XML configuration in the fabric plugin section of my pom.

Now When I run the maven build, I get *PullBuilderImageFailed* error as my openshift environment is trying to pull the fabric version of java as below.

> error: build error: unable to get fabric8/s2i-java:2.3

Ideally I want to specify to pull a java version from openshift itself FROM openshift:java. I tried specifying in my dockerfile, but its not taken up.

Is there anything elso I should do?

My fabric plugin of pom version looks like this. Should I add a dockerfile reference here?

```
              <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>   
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resource</goal>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```